What is the metaphorical meaning of "lights out"?
What is the meaning of "lights out" in this context.

DTS is a secure server management tool that enables monitoring and control of servers either via modem lines or over a network. DTS facilitates remote system administration in situations where servers are geographically distributed or physically inaccessible. DTS software works in conjunction with the DTS card provided with all Serv-Tech Apex 988 servers. The DTS card operates independently of the host server, running off 5-volt standby power from the system’s power supplies. The card also features an integral battery that gives approximately 30 minutes of backup power should a power outage occur. Thanks to these features, DTS serves as a “lights out” management tool that continues to operate even when the server operating system goes offline, the server is powered off, or a power failure occurs.

I have checked the dictionary, where it say "the time when those resident at an institution, such as soldiers in barracks or children at a boarding school, are expected to retire to bed." But this is still unclear to me. Could someone explain the metaphorical usage of "lights out" in this context?

The rest of the sentence explains it.  DTS goes on working even when the server is switched off etc., like something that continues to work at night - 'after lights out'.

The text is unclear, because it is overloaded with technical terms.  What is the source of this?  There's lots of jargon, so unless you know the jargon the paragraph means nothing much.  Perhaps if you can link to the source of this it would make more sense.   I suppose it refers to what Wikipedia calls OOB https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management

lights out= a cut in power

@Lambie That's actually not correct in this context.  James K is correct in saying that this is technical jargon.

See also What is "lights-out systems"?

I’m voting to close this question because it's about a domain-specific jargon usage, that specifically doesn't reflect either of the two common mainstream senses of "lights out" ("time to go to sleep", and power cuts).

@stangdon power outage (technical term) or power cut and lights out is just the colloquial way to say it.  /“lights out” management tool that continues to operate even when the server operating system goes offline, the server is powered off, or a power failure occurs./ Technical terms are never in inverted commas...

I've voted to close.  I think this relates to technical jargon. Also it seems that this isn't a "real" problem, but a part of a test in translation.  The OP has not been responsive to requests to provide a source.

Lights out is technical jargon in this paragraph.  You probably won't find the meaning in a standard dictionary.
In IT management, lights out refers to the ability to manage a system remotely, without a person being there.  (I think the origin of the phrase is that when people are in the building, the lights are on, but when they leave, they turn the lights off.)
So here, it means that you can do everything that you need to do completely remotely.
Source: lights-out management (LOM)

+1. A similar usage also appears in manufacturing, for processes that are automated to the point that they don’t need a human watching them and can be run overnight after everyone has gone home. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_out_(manufacturing)
